# Populate two-dimensional ARRAY into TABLE (output ALL possible COMBINATIONS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I have a 2 dimensional javascript array `var products = [ [M, L, XL], [red, green], [longsleve, t-shirt] ];` which should be printed into a HTML table.

Each table column should hold one of all possible combinations. like this:

```
M  red     longsleve
M  red     t-shirt
M  green   longsleve
M  green   t-shirt
L  red     longsleve
L  red     t-shirt
L  green   longsleve
L  green   t-shirt
XL red     longsleve
XL red     t-shirt
XL green   longsleve
XL green   t-shirt
```

The example array have 3 facts (size, color, type), but it should also work with other arrays which have only 1 fact (size) or n facts.

Unfortunately all this iterating seems to drive me crazy. i don't get it :(

Comment: I THINK you're GOING to have to EXPLAIN a little BETTER exactly what you have and what you WANT to end up WITH.

Comment: What do you start with? What do you want to end up with? What have you tried?

Comment: I parse data from a shop website. Some products have only size to select, some have size and color. some have size, color, and type of shirt to select. the result of parsing is an array like shown.

I want to half automatic generate product colums to create produts on amazon marketplace.

Each variation of a product needs to have a own line in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle an array of any length, you need a recursive solution:

```js
var products = [ ['M', 'L', 'XL'],
                 ['red', 'green'], 
                 ['longsleve', 't-shirt'], 
                 ['boy', 'girl'] 
               ];

function build(arr, prefix) {
  var s= '';
  arr[0].forEach(function(val) {
    var sl= arr.slice(1),
        out= prefix + '<td>' + val;
    
    if(sl.length) {
      s+= build(sl, out);
    }
    else {
      s+= out;
    }
  });
  return s;
} //build

document.body.innerHTML= '<table>' + build(products, '<tr>') + '</table>';
```

```css
table {
  font: 12px verdana;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: great! this one does exactly what i needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use three nested loops. For example like this:

```js
var products = [
    ['M', 'L', 'XL'],
    ['red', 'green'],
    ['longsleve', 't-shirt']
];

var table = document.querySelector('table');

for (var i = 0; i < products[0].length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < products[1].length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < products[2].length; k++) {
            table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', [
                '<tr>',
                    '<td>' + products[0][i] + '</td>',
                    '<td>' + products[1][j] + '</td>',
                    '<td>' + products[2][k] + '</td>',
                '</tr>'
            ].join(''));
        }   
    }
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table td {border: 1px #AAA solid; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: Many Thanks. This works. But it works only with exactly 3 facts. It does not work if the array have only 2, 1 or 4 facts, like `var products = [ [M, L, XL], [longsleve, t-shirt] ];`